# Why is my YongNuo YN-685 R.Slave mode not working with a YN622N-TX?

Tags: nikon, flash, yongnuo

First my setup:

1. Two YongNuo YN-685N speedlites for Nikon
2. One YongNuo YN622N-TX

My problem:

When I set my YN-685 flash into R.Slave, the YN622N-TX cannot fire the flash. But when I set my YN-685 flash in M.Slave, the YN622N-TX can fire the flash.

Setting: Both flash and trigger set in Channel 1, Group A. Or... In any other channels and groups respectively.

Comment: Is the YN-622N-TX is mix mode?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and diagnosed that the metal foot contact of the speedlight making contact on metal hotshoe of the stand was causing some interference or short. The results were repeated across all my yn685's in R slave mode causing me a lot of grief. I lined the hotshoe mount with tape and insulated the connection. Bam... Resolved the issue. Quirky I know but you might try that.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem as long as the YN622N-TX is in TTL mode for the group to which the YN685N is assigned. My problem of firing the flash is solved by putting the YN622-TX in M (manual) mode and set the YN685N in R.Slave mode. Then I can both fire the flash and control its settings remotely. However, you do lose TTL in this mode.

I have updated the 622 to v1.08 and 685 to v1.3.4 but unfortunately that did not get it to work in TTL mode either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nasty setting which will prevent the YN622N-TX and YN685N from being used together.

When the autofocus assist is enabled on the YN622N TTL will not work. Therefore, setting YN622 to TTL and YN685 to R.Slave will not fire the flash. You can verify if autofocus assist is one by checking if "AF-ILL" is depicted at the bottom right of the YN622 screen. It can be turned of by pressing the "AF/SS" button.

You can only use autofocus assist if the YN685 is in manual mode or the YN622 is in manual mode.

Why does it not work? 
Maybe Yongnuo is afraid that the autofocus assist interferes with the light metering system of the camera, which is used for TTL. However, I verified that the flash does work in TTL mode when the on-camera autofocus assist is enabled. So it must technically be possible to use the YN622 with autofocus assist and TTL. Therefore I think this is a bug in the system.